# How to increase auto height when new div appears using css or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A page has a header and footer and has two buttons (first and second button) in the body. When I click on first button a div (that has 400px height) will show and the size of the body will also increase

When I click on the second button the first div will disappear and another div that has 700px height will increase size of body.

So how can you increase the body height depending on the size of appearing div?

Comment: Please, provide us the code that you've done so far.

Comment: As long as none of the containing divs have fixed heights the container should automatically grow to accomodate. Hard to see what's wrong without any code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrap in your css, for example..

css:

```
#wrapper
{
    padding: .1em;  
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

html/or whatever file:

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- main div for the body that wraps -->
    <!-- put your functions and whatever inside the wrapper div -->
    <div> Another div you add </div>
    <div> Another div you add </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some like this:

```
var h = $(window).height() || window.innerHeight;
var w = $(window).width() || window.innerWidth;
```

Changing `window`of your class/id div